# When writing to .txt file using class function newline does not work using "\n"

Tags: python-3.x

So the newline key does not work within the text file. Anyone knows why?

## filemod.py

```
class file(object):
def __init__(self,fname,text="Test"):
    self.fname = fname + ".txt"
    self.text = text

 def writeFile(self,text,mode="a"):
            self.text = text
            f = open(self.fname,mode)
            print(f"Created file that did not exist before")
            f.write("\n"+ self.text + "\n")
            f.close()
```

## Implementation of class

```
import filemod
f1 = filemod.file("Hello")
f1.writeFile("it will")
f1.writeFile("Not work")
```

## Output .txt file

```
it willNot work
```

Comment: First, please indent your code correctly. Second, how do you know it "does not work"? Third, what is `self` and where is it defined?

Comment: Yes please also add your current output and your expected output.

Comment: And are you on windows?  Also the mode `'a'` doesn't care if the file exists, it will absolutely append to an existing file.

Comment: Yes on windows and yes i am aware what append mode does, but is it related to \n not working?

Comment: `'a'` should not be related to this issue no, it's just that you're outputting an assertion which is not true. Being on Windows however, if you're looking at the output via notepad, it doesn't use `\n` as EOL, so depending whether the version of Python you're using does or does not use universal newlines... Everything certainly works as written using Python 3.9 on linux.

Comment: Try using `os.linesep` instead of `\n`

Answer (score -1):

Guys my bad i know what the problem is. It was an human error. Case solved.

For those of you curious on what it was i'll post it below and you can guess it yourself.

```
class file(object):
def __init__(self,fname,text="Test"):
    self.fname = fname + ".txt"
    self.text = text

def readFile(self):
    if os.path.exists(self.fname):
        f = open(self.fname,"r")
        print("Open success")
        print(f.read())
        f.close()
    else:
        
        return False

 
def writeFile(self,text,mode="a"):
    self.text = text
    if os.path.exists(self.fname):
        f = open(self.fname,mode)
        f.write(self.text)
        f.close()
    
    else:
        
        f = open(self.fname,mode)
        print(f"Created file that did not exist before")
        f.write("\n"+ self.text + "\n")
        f.close()
```

So the if statement forgot to implement the "\n" when writing to file.

I should really stop using Stack overflow as if it was Reddit...